# Refactoring TestCategory properties using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, automated-refactoring

Recently I had to re-factor a large number of tests so that they all were tagged with specific a specific **TestCategory** property based on the results of a report. If the test was listed on the report it should be tagged with the "good category" otherwise it should be in the "bad category". The categories were going to be used to filter which tests would be run as part of our gated build.

Here are some examples of how it was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step in the process is to load up the solution

```cs
var wkps = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var sln = wkps.OpenSolutionAsync(slnPath).Result;
```

Now that we have a Solution reference, we can iterate through each Project and get its SyntaxTrees. We can then call GetRoot on each SyntaxTree and cast it as a CompilationUnitSyntax. From this point we search all DecsendantNodes that match our criteria of being a Method with a TestMethod property defined.

Here is what it looks like all together

```cs
foreach (var proj in sln.Projects)
{
    var comp = proj.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
    foreach (var method in root.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().Where(m => HasAttribute(m, TEST_METHOD)))
    {
        //do something with this test method
    }
}
```

There is a helper method above called HasAttribute which just looks for any Attribute on the method with the name "TestMethod". Here is what that looks like

```cs
bool HasAttribute(MethodDeclarationSyntax method, string attributeName)
{
    return method.AttributeLists
        .Any(al => al.Attributes
            .Any(a => a.Name is IdentifierNameSyntax && (((IdentifierNameSyntax)a.Name).Identifier.Text == attributeName)));
}
```

Now that we've got a way to iterate through all the TestMethod methods, we need to assign our TestCategory properties to them. This is the "do something" part of the loop above.

There are two steps to the process here. First is to edit our SyntaxTree such that we've added and/or removed the categories that we want. Second is to write that SyntaxTree back out to the source file.

The first thing we'll need to do is check the name of the method against our input list. Assuming we have a Dictionary of method names, it might look something like this

```cs
var methodName = method.Identifier.ValueText;
var testIsOnList = testDictionary.ContainsKey(methodFullName);
```

However, this test assumes that accross your whole solution, test names are globally unique.. Unfortinately in my case, this was not true. To work around this, we made the input list the "Fully Qualified Test Name" as it would appear in the MSTest test runner. This would be:

- namespace

  - class hierarchy

    - method name

ex. My.Long.NameSpace.ParentClass.ChildClass.Method

Here is a litte helper method that will create the FQTN given the MethodDeclarationSyntax

```cs
string BuildFullTestName(MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(method.Identifier.ValueText);
    SyntaxNode node = method;
    while(node.Parent is ClassDeclarationSyntax)
    {
        node = node.Parent;
        sb.Insert(0, ".");
        sb.Insert(0, ((ClassDeclarationSyntax)node).Identifier.ValueText);
    }
    if(node.Parent is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)
    {
        node = node.Parent;
        sb.Insert(0, ".");
        sb.Insert(0, ((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)node).Name.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("method \{method.Identifier.ValueText} has wierd parents.");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

So we've done our comparison and we'd like to mark a test with our good or bad TestCategory property. Here is another helper method that will take in the MethodDeclarationSyntax, property name (TestCateogry in our case), and the argument to the property (name of the cateogry in our case). It will return the new MethodDeclarationSyntax which includes our changes.

```cs
MethodDeclarationSyntax AddMethodProperty(MethodDeclarationSyntax method, string propertyName, string argumentName)
{
    return method.AddAttributeLists(
            SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(
                SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
                    SyntaxFactory.Attribute(
                        SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(propertyName),
                        SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(
                            SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(
                                SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
                                    SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
                                        SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                        SyntaxFactory.Token(
                                            default(SyntaxTriviaList),
                                            SyntaxKind.StringLiteralToken,
                                            argumentName,
                                            argumentName,
                                            default(SyntaxTriviaList))
                                        ))))))));
}
```

Because all SyntaxNodes are immutable, we can't update the method in place. So now that we've got our new MethodDeclarationSyntax we'll need to create a new SyntaxTree in which we've replaced the old method with the new one.

```cs
SyntaxTree newTree = SyntaxFactory.SyntaxTree(
    Formatter.Format(syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(method, newMethod), wkps))
        .WithFilePath(method.SyntaxTree.FilePath);
```

Note: .WithFilePath is needed so that the new SyntaxTree retains its context about which source file it maps to.

Now we can write our new SyntaxTree out to disk. Standard stuff here.

```cs
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(method.SyntaxTree.FilePath))
{
    file.Write(newTree.ToString());
    file.Flush();
}
```

There is one major gotcha to remember while looping through your methods. Each time you create a new SyntaxTree, its root CompilationUnitSyntax must be passed to future iterations of the loop. In addition, our call to syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode above will only work if the method being replaced is actually from that SyntaxTree. In other words, the MethodDeclarationSyntax reference in your next iteration of our big nested foreach will not be found in your newly created SyntaxTree. To handle this, I created another helper method that will find the MethodDeclarationSyntax in the new SyntaxTree given the old one.

```cs
MethodDeclarationSyntax GetMethodFromSyntaxRoot(CompilationUnitSyntax root, string nameSpaceName, string className, MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
{
    var result = root.Members.OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().Single(ns => ns.Name.ToString() == nameSpaceName)
       .DescendantNodes(d => true).OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single(c => c.Identifier.ValueText == className)
           .Members.OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Identifier.ValueText == method.Identifier.ValueText && m.ParameterList.ToString() == method.ParameterList.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You're skipping nested classes & namespaces.  You should use a `SyntaxNodeVisitor` to visit methods directly instead of assuming structure.

Comment: I looked at the Visitor pattern, but the DescendantNodes approach seemed much simpler and concise given that I have a very specific node filter.

Comment: Your `GetMethodFromSyntaxRoot` method is also extremely brittle; you should use the semantic model instead.

Comment: `BuildFullTestName()` doesn't handle nested namespaces.  You should replace it with http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/SymbolDisplay/SymbolDisplay.cs,30ada8e3d7348ddb